# File is not Saving

Tags: python, windows, pandas, xlsxwriter

My code is running perfectly, when i run in the cmd prompt I get no mistake. However I do not see the document MergedData anywhere.

I am using Python27 for the project

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('C://Procesos/Folder/*.xlsx'):
   df = pd.read_excel(f)
   all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MergedData.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
all_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Is there any mistake with the code?

Comment: It should be where you ran the script from!

Comment: It is probably saving, just not to the directory you're expecting. If you want to be absolutely clear where it goes, add the full path to the output ('c://dos//run//MergeData.xlsx')

Comment: Thanks it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is saved in the script's working directory.

You can easily check which is your script's directory using the following code:

```
import os
print ("Current working directory:")
print (os.getcwd())
```

It is possible to save the file in a different path specifying it in your code, the following example is using *C:/Procesos/Folder/*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('C:/Procesos/Folder/*.xlsx'):
   df = pd.read_excel(f)
   all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Procesos/Folder/MergedData.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
all_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Please also consider that writing full paths in this way is generally considered a bad idea in Python and it is often not 100% cross platform.

Here's an example about how to build a cross-platform path in Python3, using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path("source_data/text_files/raw_data.txt")

print(filename.name)
# prints "raw_data.txt"

print(filename.suffix)
# prints "txt"

print(filename.stem)
# prints "raw_data"

if not filename.exists():
    print("Oops, file doesn't exist!")
else:
    print("Yay, the file exists!")
```